# Print Pandas dataframe with index

Tags: python, pandas

say I have a panda data frame where column one is index.

```
                   A         B         C         D
2000-01-01  0.469112 -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632
2000-01-02  1.212112 -0.173215  0.119209 -1.044236
2000-01-03 -0.861849 -2.104569 -0.494929  1.071804
```

Is it possible to print a single data point based on an index? For example say I want only data for `2000-01-03` for column `C`?

Would be greatly appreciated if someone can help me with this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use loc:

```
In [11]: df.loc['2000-01-03', 'C']
Out[11]: -0.49492900000000001
```

*Note: this will work whether your index is a string or a DatetimeIndex.*

Comment: @DanAllen, I quite like at, was just in process of +1ing

Comment: @DanAllen Issue with at, is that string doesn't play nice with DatetimeIndex :(

Answer (score 0):

Andy's solution will work.  Other implementations:

```
df['C'][2]
df.ix[2]['C']
```

And in later versions of pandas

```
df.iloc[2]['C']
```

Comment: You have to be a bit careful when chaining like this, especially if you wanted to do something like `df.iloc[2]['C'] = 8` (it won't work).